# Print function selecting wrong Type of Change option excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have code below for a print function created in VBA. When I select "Return from leave" under the drop down "Type of Change", my print macro prints as a "salary" change type, not "return from leave". I cant see where I went wrong in my code or what is causing the issue... Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
Sub pcf_print()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim fs As Object
Dim str As String
Dim bool As Boolean

If Len(ActiveSheet.Name) < 3 Then
    MsgBox "This worksheet is not a PCF"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 3) <> "PCF" Then
    MsgBox "This worksheet is not a PCF"
    Exit Sub
End If

'MsgBox Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 1 - InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, " v")) 'Right(ActiveSheet.Name, 4)
If InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, " vv") Then
    If (CDbl(Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 1 - InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, " vv") - 1)) >= 1.2 And (ActiveSheet.Range("F10") = "(select)" Or ActiveSheet.Range("F10") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("F10") = "(sélect.)")) Then
        MsgBox "This form has not been completed"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    If (CDbl(Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 1 - InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, " v"))) < 1.2 And (ActiveSheet.Range("F9") = "(select)" Or ActiveSheet.Range("F9") = "")) Or (CDbl(Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 1 - InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, " v"))) >= 1.2 And (ActiveSheet.Range("F10") = "(select)" Or ActiveSheet.Range("F10") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("F10") = "(sélect.)")) Then
        MsgBox "This form has not been completed"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set datasheet = ActiveSheet

If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("CorpOrStore") = "Corp" Then
    str = "Corporate"
Else
    str = "Stores"
End If

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

bool = fs.FolderExists("H:\HR\Online PCF Archive\" & str & "\" & Trim(datasheet.Range("StoreDeptResult")) & "\")

If Not bool Then
    MkDir "H:\HR\Online PCF Archive\" & str & "\" & Trim(datasheet.Range("StoreDeptResult")) & "\"
End If

If InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, " vv") Then
    If CDbl(Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 1 - InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, " vv") - 1)) >= 1.2 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "H:\HR\Online PCF Archive\" & str & "\" & Trim(datasheet.Range("StoreDeptResult")) & "\" & Replace(datasheet.Range("F10"), "/", "_") & " for " & datasheet.Range("J17") & ", " & datasheet.Range("F17") & " effective " & Month(datasheet.Range("F12")) & "-" & Day(datasheet.Range("F12")) & "-" & Year(datasheet.Range("F12")) & ".xls"
    End If
Else
    If CDbl(Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(ActiveSheet.Name) - 1 - InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, " v"))) >= 1.2 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "H:\HR\Online PCF Archive\" & str & "\" & Trim(datasheet.Range("StoreDeptResult")) & "\" & Replace(datasheet.Range("F10"), "/", "_") & " for " & datasheet.Range("J17") & ", " & datasheet.Range("F17") & " effective " & Month(datasheet.Range("F12")) & "-" & Day(datasheet.Range("F12")) & "-" & Year(datasheet.Range("F12")) & ".xls"
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "H:\HR\Online PCF Archive\" & str & "\" & Trim(datasheet.Range("StoreDeptResult")) & "\" & datasheet.Range("F9") & " for " & datasheet.Range("J16") & ", " & datasheet.Range("F16") & " effective " & Month(datasheet.Range("F11")) & "-" & Day(datasheet.Range("F11")) & "-" & Year(datasheet.Range("F11")) & ".xls"
    End If
End If

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Payroll Forms")

If Right(ActiveSheet.Name, 5) = "v1.20" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Unprotect "0nl1n3"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B8") = "A1:G76"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B9") = "A80:G157"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B10") = "A160:G225"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B11") = "A228:G259"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B12") = "A228:G259"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B13") = "A228:G259"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B14") = "A263:G338"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B15") = "A263:G338"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B16") = "A343:G367"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B17") = "A263:G338"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B18") = "A160:G225"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("B19") = "A370:G420"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Protect "0nl1n3"
End If

If Right(ActiveSheet.Name, 5) = "v1.20" Or Right(ActiveSheet.Name, 5) = "v1.21" Or str = "Corporate" Then
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("H2")
Else
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("i2")
End If

ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "0nl1n3"
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
ws.PrintOut
ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
ActiveWorkbook.Protect "0nl1n3"

ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. You input data is not visible (no way to know which cells or tabs you are using).

Comment: As we cannot see the column headers and such, we do not know if you are referencing the wrong cell. I would double check your code by filling the form out, and the walking through your logic line by line.

Comment: Hi, yes, they already said it. We cannot help as you data references are not visible. I.e., I don't know which columns from your image are F9 & F10 or if you created a range.

Answer (score 1):

OP says:

> When I select "Return from leave" under the drop down "Type of Change", my print macro prints as a "salary" change type, not "return from leave"

Assuming that the

> "salary" change type

corresponds to the ***"default print"*** i.e.:

```
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("i2")
```

It seems that the reason the code provided always prints the default range, it's because the lines that determine the printed output are validating the `ActiveSheet.Name` instead of the value in the **"Type of Change field and print"**

**Solution proposed:**
Change these lines to reflect the cell where the **"Type of Change field and print"** is located:

*Replace `ActiveSheet.Name` with the corresponding `cell.address` i.e.: `F10` and update as required the comparisons against "v1.20" and "v1.21"*

```
If Right(ActiveSheet.Name, 5) = "v1.20" _
    Or Right(ActiveSheet.Name, 5) = "v1.21" _
        Or str = "Corporate" Then
            ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("H2")

Else
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("i2")

End If
```

It should become *(comparison values shown as a reference, they should be updated in line with the choices in the drop-down list)* :

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("F10").Value2 = "Return from leave" _
    Or str = "Corporate" Then
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("H2")

Else
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Lists").Range("i2")

End If
```

**Note**:
1. Avoid using `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet`, suggest to replace all instances of them by: `ThisWorkbook` and `datasheet` respectively.
2. Additionally, I would suggest to review and incorporate the use of [With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) and [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) throughout your procedure.

Comment: In addidion I would even recommend to use `ActiveSheet` **only once in a procedure**. If you use it more than once the active sheet might have changed between the first and the second `ActiveSheet` statement (eg by a user click or something else) and the actions perform on different sheets. So first rule *avoid `ActiveSheet` when ever possible*, second rule *if you really have to use it, then use it once to set a variable*:`Set MySheet = ActiveSheet` and replace all further `ActiveSheet` in this procedure with `MySheet`, this ensures at least that all actions are performed on *the same sheet*.

Comment: The print is not on the sheet, it's a macro I run. So it doesn't have a cell number

Comment: From the little information you are providing, it seems that: 1. You want the Type of Change value in cell `F10` to determine the range to be printed. 2. In the procedure provided the only instruction that determines the range to be printed is the PageSetup.PrintArea and it’s using the `Worksheet.Name`, not the cell you claim it should use. I can see that the macro provided does not print the range, however that macro sets the range to be printed (i.e. PageSetup.PrintArea). If that is not the case then you need to provide, the procedure you are using to print the range.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested change, what’s the result?

Comment: I agree with your remarks in your answer. However, I am wondering why you are still suggesting to compare the value in F10 with "v1.20" and "v1.21"? Shouldn't he be comparing F10 if it is "Return from leave" or "salary"

Comment: @SNicolaou Thanks for your input. However, I'm not suggesting to keep the comparison that OP is currently doing, although have to admit it's what it looks like. The reason I could not change that comparison entirely is due to the scare information provided by OP, nevertheless, I going to update the answer to indicate the change. Thanks again.

Comment: Extracted from VBA documentation
'PageSetup.PrintArea property (Excel) - Returns or sets the range to be printed as a String using A1-style references in the language of the macro. Read/write String.'

You are assigning ws.PageSetup.PrintArea a range and not a string. If you want some range to be selected to be printed you have to pass that range into a String by doing:
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea.Address

Comment: @PabloG Absolutely, that’s what the MS documentation says. However, bear in mind that the default property of the [Range object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) is `value`. Also, notice that the procedure updates several cells with a `range.address` *(although cells `H2` and `I2` are not updated by the procedure)*, therefore my fair assumption (and forced one due to the little info)  is that the cells `H2` and `I2` also contain range addresses. Could the forms "Return from leave" or "Salary" change can fit in one cell?…

Comment: @PabloG Additionally, suggest to try the following test: 
`With ActiveSheet  
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = ""  
        .Range("A1").Value = "A1:E21"  
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1")  
        Debug.Print "["; .PageSetup.PrintArea; "]"  
End With `